# Question on how to correctly use SQL Connections

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlclient

I am new to C# and am building an app which interacts with and performs various operations against SQL databases.

Here is sample syntax of what I have been using for performing these tasks up to now (this populates a combo box with a list of databases for example)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString = txtConnString.Text;
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   try
   {
      string sql = "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases;";
      conn.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (dr.Read())
      {
         comboDatabaseList.Items.Add(dr[0]);
      }
      dr.Close();
      cmd.Dispose();
   }
   catch (SqlException ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon,Error);
   }
   finally
   {
      if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
         conn.Close();
   }

}
```

However, as I'm learning and looking into things more, I understand it is best practice to wrap up SQL work in `using` blocks.

So having said that, would the following be more appropriate for the above, or is this overkill?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = txtConnString.Text;
    string sql = "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        comboDatabaseList.Items.Add(dr[0]);
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon,Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to make sure that the app is closing everything appropriately (including visual studio when I'm running debug to test the app), and the memory etc is returned to the system.

**EDIT/UPDATE:** Thanks for the responses everyone. So, in a nutshell, from what I am reading, if I use the bottom code block instead, because the `SqlConnection` is wrapped in an `using` block, I can remove the need for `dr.Close()` and `cmd.Dispose()` and I can also remove the `finally` from the `try catch finally` block?

Or can I just get rid of the try catch finally block altogether? I'm only using the `catch` to catch SQL errors, and the `finally` to close the connection, so if `using` is handling this, I don't need it do I?

I could just do this and simplify my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = txtConnString.Text;
    string sql = "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    comboDatabaseList.Items.Add(dr[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's overkill. Disposing SqlConnection closes it, along with any commands that use it and any readers created from the commands

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM like Entity Framework? While it does not absolve you from the need to dispose things, it does do a fair bit to manage resources, like connection pooling behind the scene. And it should make the example code quite a bit smaller and neater.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So I can essentially remove the finally block and the dr.Close(); and cmd.Dispose(); from the bottom code in my original post and that'll suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should wrap your SqlConnection with `using`. That means you can remove the finally block - disposing the connection will also close it, no need to so before.

Technically SqlCommands don't need to be disposed since they currently don't have any unmanaged resources, and disposing the SqlConnection will free up any resources used by SqlData Reader.

However, in my opinion it's good practice to *always* wrap any IDisposable object with using instead of relying an implementation detail like that, which could potentially change.
Others may disagree and not see it as necessary. I don't think there's any harm in it, especially when using the colon syntax to avoid nested using indentation that may harm readability.

You can use the colon syntax

```
using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

instead of

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {}
```

to lower the indentation level. When using the colon syntax, the dispose will be run at the end of the surrounding block

Comment: That's wrong. Disposing a SqlConnection also disposes any SqlCommand and SqlDataReader objects that were created from those commands.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Fair point to add, but I didn't say anything that contradicts this. I like to wrap any IDisposable in using as I then don't need to rely on an implementation detail like that which could theoretically change (even though that's admittedly very unlikely). But I will change good practice to opinion to reflect this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True but it's easy enough to just add a `using` anyway. Anyway not sure you're right https://dotnetfiddle.net/6J75uY